# Some classes can't be resolved when compiling Apache Drill?

Tags: apache, hadoop, distribute, apache-drill

I built the Drill project according to the wiki specification 
but, the project has some errors. Some classes (BigIntVector, BitHolder,BigIntHolder) can't be resolved and the workspace don't really contain these class files. Any suggestions as to what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

These clases are generated during build. 
exec/java-exec/target/generated-sources/org/apache/drill/exec/expr/holders/BigIntHolder.java
There is a problem in that the Maven import into eclipse results in target/generated-sources/org being added to the Source Folder build path. I have found that in the two cases, comon and java-exec, if you remove these folders from the source folder build path and add them as target/generated-sources this will help.

This is a workaround, there is obviously a misconfigured pom.xml somewhere.

Comment: In Intellij Idea you can mark directory `drill/exec/vector/target/generated-sources` as a generated sources root (right button -> mark directory as -> generated sources root). Works fine for me.